# XML parsing: line 1, character 63, A string literal was expected

Tags: sql-server, xml

When executing a procedure Iam facing  error

XML parsing: line 1, character 63, A string literal was expected

`

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Icn_GetResultCountForAllAdvancedSearch]
        @sqtype = 1,
        @UserID = 615,
        @AdvancedSearchQuery = N'<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<Searches xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\r\n  <Search SearchId=\"2447\" Query=\" where   ([FLD5283] IS NOT NULL and [FLD5283] &lt;&gt; '''')   and 5263 IN (Select FieldID from Icn_ContractFieldsEntry icfe where icfe.ContractID=z1.ContractID)    AND ( Archive &lt;&gt;''true'' OR Archive is null)\" />\r\n  <Search SearchId=\"2439\" Query=\" where   ([FLD5399] IS NOT NULL and [FLD5399] &lt;&gt; '''')     AND ( Archive &lt;&gt;''true'' OR Archive is null)\" />\r\n  <Search SearchId=\"2386\" Query=\" where   ([ContractId] IS NOT NULL and (case when CONVERT(varchar(max),[ContractId])='''' then ''0'' else [ContractId] end) &lt;&gt; (''0''))    AND ( Archive &lt;&gt;''true'' OR Archive is null)\" />\r\n</Searches>'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text you've shown here:

```
@AdvancedSearchQuery = N'<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<Searches ...>\r\n</Searches>'
```

Is not a valid piece of XML that SQL Server knows what to do with. The `\"` escapes are reminiscent of how `"` characters are escaped in C# strings. No such escapes are required for `"` in SQL because its string delimiter is `'` instead. `\r\n`, similarly, look like C# (or C, etc) escape sequences, which aren't supported in SQL server strings.

To have a newline in an SQL string, just enter a newline without closing the string, or append strings with `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` in the appropriate places - but to use this second form, you'd need to construct `@AdvancedSearchQuery` separately from invoking the stored procedure - you can either pass parameters or string literals when invoking procedures, not expressions.